# Data quality - Missing values (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, data-quality

I'm working on a data quality project. I'm trying to generate a data quality report using pandas-profiling profileReport but when i verify the report it says that i have no missing values while i do have empty cells.
Or do you have any other suggestion
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7BxC.png)

```
df = pd.read_excel('D:/SDAD/PFE/bi_bpcustomer.xls')
print(df.dtypes)
reportCl=ProfileReport(df)
reportCl.to_file(output_file='rapportClient.html')
```

Here's a part of my xls file showing missing cells:
[xls file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcCk0.png)

Comment: What is it returning for `df.isnull()` ?

Comment: It returns False for every col but i have missing values

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of your original xls file? Better a part with missing values.

Comment: @PieCot i added it in the post

Comment: @biihu, null, empty and blank r all different things, u should use the equivalent of Apache common's `StringUtils.isBlank()` (in Java), Pls feel free to DM me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, i found a way by adding this to my code:

```
missing_values = [""," "]
client= pd.read_excel('D:/SDAD/PFE/bi_bpcustomer.xls',na_values = 
missing_values)
```